# Cannot add iptables firewall rules properly to Docker container

Tags: docker, iptables

I want to create a firewall to Docker container that allows only some IPs and rejects others.

The default setting was like this:

```
$ sudo iptables --list
Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

As documented on the Docker document, this allows all incoming IPs.
So I'm modifying this. I ran the following commands:

```
sudo iptables -D DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -s xx.xx.xx.xx,yy.yy.yy.yy -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -j DROP
```

This should have worked,
my expected result is that if I try to access to the server from the zz.zz.zz.zz IP, it will be rejected, but from xx.xx.xx.xx, it will be passed.

But the result now is, whether I'm accessing from xx.xx.xx.xx (or yy.yy.yy.yy) or zz.zz.zz.zz, the page told me "Failed to connect". So apparently it's being dropped.

I have no idea what is happening, what is cause of this problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `-i` option as documented.

```
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 ! -s your.ip.add.res -j DROP
```